# seldon-batch-processor CLI install

Tags: kubernetes, seldon, seldon-core

I've been exploring the batch processing of Seldon: https://docs.seldon.io/projects/seldon-core/en/latest/servers/batch.html, but I couldn't find documentation that shows how to install the CLI `seldon-batch-processor`. Can anyone show me how to install it?

Comment: It looks like it was answered here: https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/issues/2956. As you were the creator of this question, please post it as an answer so it will be more visible to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since I received a lot of support from Github (https://github.com/SeldonIO/seldon-core/issues/2956) and it has been solved, I'll post my answer.

We should either `pip install seldon-core` or use their Docker Images.
If you're using their Docker images, make sure to upgrade the seldon-core version to 1.2.0+, the earlier versions don't have the batch processing functionality.